# Get total [checkbox] value

Tags: php, arrays

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[book]" value="10" /> book
<input type="checkbox" name="product[plane]" value="20" /> plane
```

**PHP:**

```
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $name => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

How to get the total (sum) `value` if the user select two fields (book & plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you have an array of product. If you foreach that, create a $total = 0; at the start, add the value to it, at the end you have a total.

You can check that would work by  `print_r($_POST)` and you'll see any selected values show as part of an array within the array of $_POST.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_sum](http://php.net/array_sum):

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $_POST['product']));
```

Assuming you already checked validity of the `$_POST['product']` field.

Comment: You should use at least `floatval()` to allow values like `5.50`, or even `12.00`. Update: Ah, I see, the values should be integer. Thus `intval()` is ok here :)

Comment: I assumed integers were in play. If not, I guess he would point that out in the example. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   $total=0;
   foreach ($_POST['product'] as $k) {   
    $total +=$k;
}    
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pTotal = 0;
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $pVal)
{
  $pTotal += intval($pVal,10);
}
```

Make sure you're explicit about the format type.  Without checking, I would expect the values coming in to be strings, not integers... which will give you all sorts of headaches if you're trying to add them up.  : )